# Sorting Data on a Graph. Value not align to Key:Value pair

Tags: python, sorting, matplotlib, graphing

I am trying to sort my values on the X axis but the values from the Y-Axis do not align with the Key:Value pair from the counter.

If you see a picture of the graph below that was printed, it printed the Y values in order as I want, but the X values that are being displayed do not align.

File: https://drive.google.com/file/d/11niYTryMzcCZOraEoqd3FltDZfyRyDEG/view?usp=sharing

Graph:

[image]

Code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import statistics
import random
from collections import Counter

ip = []
time = []


# open the file
nasaFile = open("NASA_access_log_Jul95", 'r')
try:
    for i in nasaFile:
        splitLines = i.split(" ")
        ip.append(splitLines[0])
        time.append(splitLines[3])
except IndexError:
    pass
except UnicodeDecodeError:
    print("there is a unicode error")
print("This IP is recurring:" , statistics.mode(ip))
print("This time is busy: ", statistics.mode(time))

#sorting the data

counter1 = Counter(ip)
print(counter1)
sss= sorted(counter1.values(),reverse=True)

# Graph 1


fig,ax=plt.subplots()
ax.bar(counter1.values(),sss)

plt.xlim([0 , 15])
plt.ylim([0 , 1450])
plt.xticks(rotation=45)
plt.show()
# Graph 2

plt.plot()
```

Comment: Could you please edit your code to make it a [mre]? In particular, get rid of the `open("NASA_access_log_Jul95", 'r')` that we can't reproduce. Perhaps write a small code that reproduces your issue with dummy values for `x` and `y`?

Comment: data file is too big : 196MB, please do a small sample file or data sample and/or include it in your code. See [MRE].